# Need primary key information in Debezium connector for postgres insert events

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, amazon-aurora, debezium

I am using Debezium connector for postgres with Kafka connect.

For an insert row event written to Kafka by the connector, I need information about which columns are primary keys and which are not. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Pasting a sample insert event generated in Kafka:

```
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "type": "int32",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "id"
          },
          {
            "type": "int32",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "bucket_type"
          }
        ],
        "optional": true,
        "name": "postgresconfigdb.config.alert_configs.Value",
        "field": "before"
      },
      {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "type": "int32",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "id"
          },
          {
            "type": "int32",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "bucket_type"
          }
        ],
        "optional": true,
        "name": "postgresconfigdb.config.alert_configs.Value",
        "field": "after"
      },
      {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "version"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "connector"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "name"
          },
          {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "ts_ms"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": true,
            "name": "io.debezium.data.Enum",
            "version": 1,
            "parameters": {
              "allowed": "true,last,false"
            },
            "default": "false",
            "field": "snapshot"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "db"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "schema"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "table"
          },
          {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": true,
            "field": "txId"
          },
          {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": true,
            "field": "lsn"
          },
          {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": true,
            "field": "xmin"
          }
        ],
        "optional": false,
        "name": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source",
        "field": "source"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "op"
      },
      {
        "type": "int64",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "ts_ms"
      },
      {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "id"
          },
          {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "total_order"
          },
          {
            "type": "int64",
            "optional": false,
            "field": "data_collection_order"
          }
        ],
        "optional": true,
        "field": "transaction"
      }
    ],
    "optional": false,
    "name": "postgresconfigdb.config.alert_configs.Envelope"
  },
  "payload": {
    "before": null,
    "after": {
      "id": 1100,
      "bucket_type": 10
    },
    "source": {
      "version": "1.2.0.Final",
      "connector": "postgresql",
      "name": "postgresconfigdb",
      "ts_ms": 1599830887858,
      "snapshot": "true",
      "db": "configdb",
      "schema": "config",
      "table": "alert_configs",
      "txId": 2139888,
      "lsn": 379356048,
      "xmin": null
    },
    "op": "r",
    "ts_ms": 1599830887859,
    "transaction": null
  }
}
```

Here the columns in the table are 'id' and 'bucket_type', the values of which are reported in the json-path payload->after.

There is information about columns which are not null in the column specific 'optional' boolean field, however no information about which columns are primary keys. (id in this case)

Comment: Is it ok to that manually? You can use Kafka Connect SMT to extract PK field into message key and then use it on consumer side

Answer (score 2):

you find information about what fields are PK columns in Kafka key.